# how to make create a random combination of fixed lenght using python

Tags: python, combinations, fixed

I want to make a list of a fixed amount of values from random elements of a list. I get an error whit this assumption:

```
import random                                                               

ALL_COLORS = ("red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "white")          


def create_combination(nb_elements):                                        
    i = 0                                                                   
    combination = ""                                                        
    while i < nb_elements:                                                  
        combination += random.choice(ALL_COLORS)                            
        i += 1                                                              
    print(combination, sep=", ")                                            
    return (combination)                                                    


for i in range(10):                                                         
    combination = create_combination                                        
    assert len(combination) == i    

for color in combination:                                               
    assert color in ALL_COLORS
```

Comment: You indenting is broken.  Please fix.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right for SO to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is overcomplicated.

Here is one way you can implement what you might be looking for:

```
import random

colours = ("red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "white")

result = [random.choice(colours) for _ in range(10)]

# Example output
# ['orange', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'white', 'orange', 'red']
```

There are many issues with your existing code which make it unusable:

- No indentation.
- Concatenating strings instead of adding to lists. If you need to concatenate strings, you can easily perform this as a final step on your list of strings.
- You then check length of your result which, if anything, will be a string such as "orangeredblueyellow...".
- Simple loops such as this can be replaced by list comprehensions.